# Summarize by column: mean and sum

Tags: r

I am trying to summarize a list of variables by group. Some varibles need to be summed and others need to be averaged.

I have this:

```
Group    Variable1     Variable2
1        10            2
1        12            6
2        6             7
2        4             9
```

I'd like the sum of variable 1 and mean of variable 2:

```
Group    Variable1     Variable2
1        22            4
2        10            8
```

I've been using dplyr to get the group sum:

```
sum <- (df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum)))
```

I'm trying to find a way to choose which columns are summed and which are averaged for the summarize function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with the devel version of `dplyr` to selectively apply different functions on different set of variables with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>%
   summarise(across(Variable1:Variable2, sum), across(Variable3:Variable5, mean))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Group Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4 Variable5
#  <int>     <int>     <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1        22         8      18.5         5      24  
#2     2        10        16      11           7      20.5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Variable1 = c(10L, 
12L, 6L, 4L), Variable2 = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 9L), Variable3 = c(24L, 
13L, 10L, 12L), Variable4 = c(3L, 7L, 9L, 5L), Variable5 = c(26L, 
22L, 23L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Example data with more columns:

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Variable1 = c(10L, 
12L, 6L, 4L), Variable2 = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 9L), Variable3 = c(9L, 
8L, 10L, 2L), Variable4 = c(8L, 7L, 9L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

#    Group Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4
# 1:     1        10         2         9         8
# 2:     1        12         6         8         7
# 3:     2         6         7        10         9
# 4:     2         4         9         2         5
```

Create vectors of variable names and use `mget` + `lapply` in data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, c(lapply(mget(paste0('Variable', 1:2)), sum), 
       lapply(mget(paste0('Variable', 3:4)), mean)),
   by = Group]

#    Group Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4
# 1:     1        22         8       8.5       7.5
# 2:     2        10        16       6.0       7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `merge` + `aggregate`, i.e

```
dfout <- merge(aggregate(Variable1~Group,df,sum),
               aggregate(Variable2~Group,df,mean))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Group Variable1 Variable2
1     1        22         4
2     2        10         8
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Variable1 = c(10L, 
12L, 6L, 4L), Variable2 = c(2L, 6L, 7L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate_at` to apply functions to multiple columns and then select 1st row in each group to get summarised values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Variable1:Variable2), sum) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Variable3:Variable4), mean) %>%
  slice(1L)

#  Group Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4
#  <int>     <int>     <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1        22         8       8.5       7.5
#2     2        10        16       6         7
```